# Remove customer account from Softlayer Brand Account

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

i have create the customer account under softlayer master Account using python client

> User creation

```
import SoftLayer 
client = SoftLayer.Client(
              username= username,
              api_key = apiKey,
             )
try:
   result = client['Brand'].createCustomerAccount(cust_account)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
   print("Error: %s, %s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

How to remove customer from master account,i have refer the api [SoftLayer_Brand](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand) couldn't seen any method to remove customer account from master brand

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to submit a ticket. Only the softLayere's employees have the permissions to delete customer's account.

Comment: Nope only softlayer's employees can remove the customer;s account